# How to validate content-type using regex?

Tags: regex

I need to validate the request Accept header using regex (python). The regex must match application/json or application/jose+jwe and additional parameters (charset=utf8 and q value).

Originally the requirements to only accept application/json and q value and no other mimi types. I had the following regex that worked.

`(^application/json;q=(0|1|(0\.[1-9]))$)|(^application/json$)`

I know need to be able to include the charset paremeter to `charset=utf8` and be able to match anywhere in the line.

I am new to regex and created the following regex but it does not match all the requirements (https://regex101.com/r/vFMCcI/11) -

`(application/json; q=(0|1|(0\.[1-9])))$|(application\/json; charset=utf8)|(application\/json; charset=utf8 q=(0|1|(0\.[1-9])))|(application/json)`

The test strings are

```
application/json,
application/json; q=0.2
application/json; charset=utf8
application/json; q=0.2 charset=utf8
application/json; charset=utf8 q=0.2
text/html, application/json; q=0.2, application/pdf

application/jose+jwe
application/jose+jwe; q=0.2
application/jose+jwe; charset=utf8
application/jose+jwe; q=0.2 charset=utf8
application/jose+jwe; charset=utf8 q=0.2
text/html, application/jose+jwe; q=0.2, application/pdf
```

1. Why am I only getting partial matches for `application/json; charset=utf8 q=0.2`?
2. The regex is getting too long when application/jose+jwe is not even included. It is adding on ms to the requests. Any pointers on this can be better optimised?

EDIT:

Q value must be 0-1 and only to 1 decimal place

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
```

The only acceptable charset value is `charset=utf8`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more specific pattern.

```
^application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;(( q=(1|0\.\d))|( charset.utf8))+)?$
```

This will match what you described above. On the first test case there is a trailing comma but I wasn't sure if you wanted to include that. It's a simple add though.

```
^application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;(( q=(1|0\.\d))|( charset.utf8))+)?,?$
```

Comment: This is great, a lot closer to what I have been trying to achieve. I do need the trailing comma as it maybe used if other MIME types are submitted - `^application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;(( q=(1|0\.\d))|( charset.utf8))+)?,?$`. The only issue is it is not matching the MIME type when it does not start with application/json (in between two MIME types or at the end). Example it is failing for `text/html, application/json; q=0.2, application/pdf` and `text/html, application/json; q=0.2,`

Comment: Update - this allows matching anywhere in the line  `application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;(( q=(1|0\.\d))|( charset.utf8))+)?,?` However it know matches `application/jsonjargon` which should be a failed match...

Comment: It matches anywhere in the line though  - `application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;(( q=(1|0\.\d))|( charset=utf8))+)?,?` 


Although it is now matching it incorrectly matches when additional characters are included after the match i.e.application/json; charset=utf8 q=0.1jargon.

https://regex101.com/r/jTvo6j/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex. It works with optional "q" and optional "charset"

```
application\/(json|jose\+jwe)(;\s)?((charset=utf8|q=[0-1]\.\d)(\s)?)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/ABjXH4/5

Comment: This much improved than my regex. I should have been clearer. 

- Only `charset=utf8` is allowed. Your regex is accepting anything after charset.
- it is matching `application/pdf` which i do not need. I believe this is because any values are allowed after q?
- q value must be integer only. I read somewhere it is only to 1 decimal point.

Comment: Ok I have changed a few things, look at the regex and the link again.

Comment: Sorry my explanation is not clear and precise. I have updated the question. q value must be between 0-1 (1 decimal place) and only acceptable charset value is `charset=utf8`. Also if paremeters are included they must be valid . If you look at the bottom line in the updated request (https://regex101.com/r/ABjXH4/4) `application/jose+jwe; jargon` should be a failed request. This where i am getting confused

Comment: I have build another optional step which should work